# RxJava2 - Transfer downstream errors upstream

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to work with a RxJava library for bluetooth on Android. My requirements are:

1. An observable to monitor the connection status
2. The connection automatically restarts on any error
3. An observable to listen for messages from the connection

This is what I have so far, but I can't help but think it is convoluted. Primarily, my concern is that the way I forced the errors from downstream to cause a new connection to be created. Specifically, its me using the `mCommErrors` publish subject down when I receive a read/parsing error.

I think all of this is necessary because my client's will always be connected to the observable created in observeIsConnected() which prevents the `refCount()` going to 0 upon any error.

Thanks for any insight you might be able to provide. I have much larger problems with a deadlock involving the refCount() operator so Im trying to weed out any of the potential "bad things" I've done.

```
public class MyBluetoothDevice
{   
    private final MessageParser mParser;
    private final Observable<MyBluetoothConnection> mConnectionObservable;
    // The comms errors will be piped in so we can restart our connection as needed. These errors
    // can originate post-connection when reading / sending messages
    private final PublishSubject<Throwable> mCommsErrors = PublishSubject.create();

public MyBluetoothDevice(BluetoothDevice device, MessageParser parser, Scheduler scheduler)
{
    mParser = parser;

    mConnectionObservable = mCommsErrors
            .switchMap(err -> Observable.<BluetoothSocket> error(err))
            .mergeWith(createConnection(device, SPP_UUID))
            .subscribeOn(scheduler)
            .map(MyBluetoothConnection::new)
            .retryWhen(err -> err.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .replay(1)
            .refCount();
}

// Copy this from RxBluetooth since they forget to close the bluetooth socket if an error occurs
private Observable<BluetoothSocket> createConnection(final BluetoothDevice device, final UUID uuid)
{
    return Observable.create(emitter -> {
        try {
            final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            emitter.setCancellable(() -> silentlyCloseSocket(bluetoothSocket));
            // We don't have to handle closing the socket if connect fails, because setCancellable
            // will cause the socket to be closed when the error is emitted
            bluetoothSocket.connect();
            emitter.onNext(bluetoothSocket);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            emitter.onError(e);
        }
    });
}

private void silentlyCloseSocket(BluetoothSocket socket)
{
    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException ignore) {
    }
}

public Observable<Boolean> observeIsConnected()
{
    return mConnectionObservable
            .switchMap(MyBluetoothConnection::observeIsConnected);
}

public Observable<TruPulseMessage> observeMessages()
{
    return mConnectionObservable
            .switchMap(connection -> connection
                    .observeStringLineStream()
                    .switchMap(mParser::parse)
                    .doOnError(err -> connection.closeConnection())
                    .doOnError(err -> mCommsErrors.onNext(err))
                    .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
                    );
}

public Completable send(String command)
{
    return mConnectionObservable
            .take(1)
            .concatMapCompletable(connection -> connection.sendCommand(command))
            .doOnError(mCommsErrors::onNext);
}
}
```

and here is the MyBluetoothConnection

```
public class MyBluetoothConnection
{
private final BluetoothSocket mSocket;
private final InputStream mInputStream;
private final OutputStream mOutputStream;
private final BehaviorSubject<Boolean> mIsConnected;
private Observable<String> mOutObservable;

MyBluetoothConnection(BluetoothSocket socket) throws Exception
{
    if (socket == null) {
        throw new InvalidParameterException("Bluetooth socket can't be null");
    }

    this.mSocket = socket;
    this.mIsConnected = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(Boolean.TRUE);

    try {
        mInputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        mOutputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        closeConnection();
        throw new IOException("Can't get stream from bluetooth socket", e);
    }
}

public Observable<Boolean> observeIsConnected()
{
    return mIsConnected;
}

public Observable<String> observeStringLineStream()
{
    if (mOutObservable == null) {
        mOutObservable = Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<String>) emitter -> {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mInputStream));
            try {
                String line = "";
                while (!emitter.isDisposed() && line != null) {
                    line = reader.readLine();
                    if (line != null)
                        emitter.onNext(line);
                    else
                        emitter.onComplete();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                closeConnection();
                if (!emitter.isDisposed())
                    emitter.onError(e);
            }
        }).share();
    }
    return mOutObservable;
}

public Completable sendCommand(String command)
{
    return Completable.create(emitter -> {
        if (!mIsConnected.getValue()) {
            emitter.onError(new IOException("BluetoothConnection is disconnected"));
            return;
        }

        String line = command + "\r\n";
        try {
            mOutputStream.write(line.getBytes());
            mOutputStream.flush();
            emitter.onComplete();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Error occurred. Better to close terminate the connection
            closeConnection();
            if (!emitter.isDisposed())
                emitter.onError(new IOException("Can't send Bluetooth command", e));
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Close the streams and socket connection.
 */
public void closeConnection()
{
    if (!mIsConnected.getValue())
        return;

    try {
        if (mInputStream != null) {
            mInputStream.close();
        }

        if (mOutputStream != null) {
            mOutputStream.close();
        }

        if (mSocket != null) {
            mSocket.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    } finally {
        mIsConnected.onNext(Boolean.FALSE);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you have two separate observer chains. If your main observer chain establishes the connection, reads the strings from the connection, throws errors, and completes, then you can apply your retry logic to the one observer chain. The `using()` operator constructs an observable item that will close itself upon termination. The `switchMap()` operator will close the connection upon error or termination, and open a fresh one when a new socket is created.

```
createConnection( device, id )
  .switchMap( socket -> Observable.using( 
                        () -> new MyBlueToothConnection( socket ),
                        connection -> connection.observeStringLineStream(),
                        connection -> connection.close() ) )
 .retryWhen( err -> err.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) )
 ...
```

This observable will emit strings from the blue tooth device for as long as you need.

Comment: Bob, I am relatively new to this framework so I'll try best to explain myself. I am reusing the mConnectionObservable because I use it one time to listen on the connection state (in observeIsConnected) and, then again, to chain into the string processing observable. I was thinking that I could just use a BehaviourSubject and use doOnNext/doOnError to to pass a True/False into it in this chain. I thought doing it the way I had it was "cleaner" but I could be wrong. Finally, I omitted another case where I use the connection observable to send, and want to "reconnect" if that errors as well

Comment: I edited in the sending. Sorry I was trying to reduce the sheer amount of code I had to post to get my point across